# PHP - download pdf file from link and save in local file folder

Tags: php, pdf

I am trying to get through an API, a live open access pdf file, and then download that file to my server. 
However the PDF file does not end with a ".pdf" extension but is encapsulated in a more complexe url:
http://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.4996175
A web browser would simply ask to open or save it as a PDF file, whereas my script cannot translate it as such.
How can I make my PHP script recognize this url as a PDF file?
Thanks in advance.
Olivier

Comment: are you trying to download to the server from the wild? if so, did you tried simply curling that? or even `file_put_contents("file.pdf",file_get_contents("URL"));` should work but is definitely not what I would recomend.

Comment: I tried with Curl but the problem is that the URL itself does not contain anything: it is the call of this URL which causes the formatting of the PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what exactly you are doing and why your php script has to recognize pdf.

If you are loading the file by your php application - you can check content type header of the file, which contains file type information along with the extension. You can use http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php library for it.

If you want to let users download the file on your site - you have to set correct content type like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

Now the browser will know that the file you are serving is pdf even without extension.

**Update**

Eventually it turned out that the site with pdf files just required some cookies, as described below.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It must recognize it to be able to save it in a dedicated folder. For files with the PDF extension, I use the 'copy' function and everything works.
I do not want users to save the file, this is not the goal.

Comment: Could you provide a lines of your code which does not work to clarify the problem? Like copy('http:/aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.4996175', './somefile.pdf'));

Comment: Here is the code portion:
`code`
if ($urlPDF != "")//PDF URL found with the first method
{
  if (!copy($urlPDF, './PDF/'.$titPDF.'.pdf', $context))
  {
    //echo('Unable to copy file');
  }else{
    //echo (mime_content_type('./PDF/'.$titPDF.'.pdf').'<br>');
    if(mime_content_type('./PDF/'.$titPDF.'.pdf') != "application/pdf")
    {//deleting the file
      unlink('./PDF/'.$titPDF.'.pdf');
    }
  }
}
`code`

Comment: When i tried do copy the file myself, in the downloaded copy i found this: <meta name="pbContext" content=";wgroup:string:Publication Websites;website:website:aip-site;page:string:Cookie Absent"/>. Probably this is the problem. You have to pass some cookie to get the correct file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
<a href="http://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.4996175" download="sample.pdf" id="pdf_file">Download PDF</a>
```

If you want to do the auto download without showing the anchor tag on page, then you can set JavaScript or Jquery code. To do this, set `display:none;` to the anchor tag and then you can trigger `click` event using jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pdf_file').trigger('click');
};)
```

So it will start downloading the file when page loads.

If you want to grab the file and store it on your server then you can do that using this:

```
file_put_contents("sample.pdf",file_get_contents("URL"));
```

You can use absolute path instead just file name and you would get the file stored at the defined folder of your server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried but the download does not start. In addition, what I want is that my server receives the download, as if it was with the PHP function 'copy'

Comment: @OTroccaz, I have updated my answer now. Take a look.

Comment: I tested: I do not recover the PDF but the html code of a page resembling a search engine of the site http://aip.scitation.org/

Answer (score 0):

@Oleg Loginov, you are right : just adding a cookie in the context, and the PDF is well uploaded via a copy command.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
));
```

Many thanks!